# If there exist a type with no method can you consider it a object?

Tags: function, go, methods, types

To have an object do we need to have both a type declaration and a method?

```
 type IntSet { 
         words []uint64
    }

func (s *IntSet) Method(x int) int {}
```

i.e you declare a type:

```
type IntSet { 
     words []uint64
}
```

but leave it as is can this still be considered a object?

Comment: [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) uses the word object once (probably by mistake). What do you mean by object?.

Comment: Strictly speaking, Go doesn't have "objects" at all. But people still refer to many values (with or without methods) as objects. You can call it what you like.

Answer (score 0):

Typically an object an instance of any type. A type without methods is still a type it is just explaining what it holds and what can manipulate it.

You might be thinking of classes which golang technically doesn't have but you can think of types + methods as classes-ish. Without the methods they are closer to structs.

Answer (score -1):

The combination of a type declaration and a method definition doesn't instantiate any memory. So there's no "object" in either the former or the latter case.

To make an "object" in the golang-sense, you have to use new() or make() or the literal syntax, which creates an "instance" of the type and assigns it to a var:

```
intset := IntSet{ words: []uint64{1,2,3,4} }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BFdRL2HBbRp

Comment: There is no "object" in the golang-sense at all.

Comment: Disagree. For a beginner, a thing with identity, encapsulation, composition, dispatch- this is sufficiently close to "object". "You can call it what you like", eh? :)

Comment: Traditionally, objects are "instances of classes." Go has no classes, therefore no objects.  It has many similarities, and colloquially, many Go programmers refer to "objects".  But technically, Go does not have objects, so a technical discussion should not conflate these terms.  Colloquially, I don't care what you or anyone else call them. I use the term 'object', too--but not in a technical discussion, which this is.

Comment: Disagree, this question is a conceptual teaching moment, not a discussion of terminology. Use the learners terminology to build the conceptual understanding, into which terminological precision can grow.